# convert image to .wav file and vice versa python

Tags: python, tkinter

i have tried doing conversion by getting each pixel value, then converting it into byte format and then writing it as .wav file. However the output file does not play. What am I doing wrong?

```
        import cv2
    import numpy

    from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

    file_path = askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/Users/Batman/Documents/Programming/tkinter/",
                               filetypes =(("jpg", "*.jpg"),("All Files","*.*")),
                               title = "Choose a file."
                               )


    img=cv2.imread(file_path,1)
    cv2.imshow('original',img)

    height, width, channels = img.shape

    s = b''

    for x in range(height):
        for y in range(width):
            for z in range(3): 
                int_num=int(img[x][y][z])

                s = s+ bytes([int_num])

    file = open("sbytes.wav", 'wb')
    file.write(s)
    file.close()

    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: And where is the *wav* header?